# I was afraid he would offer vs I was afraid he offered

Tags: verbs, conditional-constructions

Are both sentences below grammatically correct and do they mean the same?

- I was afraid he would offer me meat.
- I was afraid he offered me meat.

Answer (score 1):

> I was afraid he would offer me meat.
>
> I was afraid he offered me meat.

Only the first makes sense to me. I cannot think of a context in which the second would be correct.

**I was afraid he would offer me meat**

This means that he hadn't offered anything yet. You were concerned that if he were to offer you food in the (near) future, he would offer meat.

**I was afraid he offered me meat.**

The only way I can make sense of this is to split it into two sentences, i.e.

*I was afraid. He offered me meat.*

This means that for some reason you were afraid of this person (maybe he had captured you as a hostage). Then at some point during this experience he actually did offer you some meat.

Comment: The past example works if the two involved don't have a common language, and are making signs at each other, for example. (Although '...he had offered...' would be better.)